# When are objects copied in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, copy

I am trying to understand when are objects copied in Python.

The easy case is explicit copy, for example:

```
A = [ 1,2,3 ]
B = list(A) # this is a copy of A
```

Are there scenarios which implicitly copy an object? For example some languages using "pass by value" will copy objects used as functions arguments (I know that this is not the case in Python). Are there such examples of implicit copy in Python?

Comment: No items get implicitly copied in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it will better illustrate what is happening in your code:

```
>>> a = object()
>>> b = object()
>>> A = [a, b]
>>> B = list(A)
>>> A
[<object object at 0x1002b7090>, <object object at 0x1002b70a0>]
>>> B
[<object object at 0x1002b7090>, <object object at 0x1002b70a0>]
>>> A is B
False
```

What you can see is `list()` actually creates a new instance of a list based on A. This is why `A is B` returns false. However the contents of both list are identical

Answer (score -1):

In practical terms, any indirect assignment of an immutable object can be considered a copy. For example:

```
a = "abc"
b = a
a += "def"
print b
--> "abc"
```

Technically, there is no copying occurring. When you add to a, you are actually creating a new object and assigning the variable name "a" to it while the variable "b" continues to reference the original string.

As far as functions go, there is no copying that occurs in passed variables; however, the same rules apply for mutable and immutable arguments. If you were to pass an immutable object, any changes would only impact the local "copy".

Comment: How so? If the OP is asking about pass-by-copy, I would think mutability and under-the-hood variable assignment is a natural extension as it is (IMO) one of the key differences between Python and those languages that allow explicit pointer, etc. control.

Answer (score -2):

`list()` is not doing anything special in your example.

> [list(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list):
>
> Return a list whose items are the same and in the same order as
> iterable‘s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a container that
> supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable is already a
> list, a copy is made and returned, similar to iterable[:]. For
> instance, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and list( (1, 2, 3) )
> returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, returns a new empty list,
> [].

Comment: True, but it does demonstrate what the OP is describing. B now references a list separate from that of A.